# replace placeholders in string

Tags: c#, string, macros

I have strings like below:

```
Insert into Emp(Id,Name,Number,Address) values({Id},"Abc",{Number},{Address});
```

In above string `{Id}` ,`{Number}` and `{Address}` are placeholders  which I want to replace with some values.

I want list of placeholders from the string and I want to easily replace it with actual values.

output should be like this:

```
Insert into Emp(Id,Name,Number,Address) values(123,'Abc',55668878,'test address');
```

Comment: Have a look at string interpolation. BUT! better still - just use parameterized queries or some ORM to manage queries to database

Comment: If this is all about SQL statements I hardly recommend using parameters to avoide SQL Injection.

Comment: It's code demand.

Comment: Is it SQL question? or C# string interpolation question.

Comment: C# string interpolation question

Comment: As a side note - it is more correct to call it place holders rather than macros

Comment: I want List of placeholders too.. and as per placeholders i will change values.. placeholders will be different every time.

Comment: @Milanchavda -what do you mean?

Comment: In above example I provided only one string(query). I have multiple strings(queries) for multiple tables @GiladGreen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you receive your string in a variable you should do interpolation by yourself

To do so, you need to find all placeholders and replace they value. You can do this with regular expression (can be simplified if placeholder can start with digits)

```
{(?<placeholder>[a-z_][a-z0-9_]*?)}
```

Next method will do this replacement:

```
public static string Replace(string input, Dictionary<string, object> replacement)
{
    var regex = new Regex("{(?<placeholder>[a-z_][a-z0-9_]*?)}",
        RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

    return regex.Replace(input, m =>
    {
        var key = m.Groups["placeholder"].Value;
        if (replacement.TryGetValue(key, out var value))
            return value.ToString();

        throw new Exception($"Unknown key {key}");
    });
}
```

Usage:

```
var input = "Insert into Emp(Id,Name,Number,Address) values({Id},\"Abc\",{Number},{Address});";
var replaces = new Dictionary<string, object>
{
    {"Id", 123},
    { "Number", 55668878},
    {"Address", "\"test address\"" },
};

var result = Replace(input, replaces);
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Ouput:

> Insert into Emp(Id,Name,Number,Address) values(123,"Abc",55668878,"test address");

Answer (score 2):

If your string is already in the format of `{variable}` then it is perfect for using [string interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated):

```
var Id=1, Number=2;
var Address = "Some address";

string str = $"Insert into Emp(Id,Name,Number,Address) values({Id},\"Abc\",{Number},{Address});"
```

Another option, if you have many such strings, each with their own place holder collection is to iterate such collection of placeholder and use `string.Replace` between the placeholder and the desired value (for instance if this collection of placeholders is a lookup table with the key as the placeholder string and the values as the desired values).

**However**, as I commented, I really really encourage you to not use methods like this for creating your queries. This is risky as it is susceptible for SQL Injections. Instead use parameterized queries or better still some ORM to your database.

Comment: Guess you forgot to replace the `@`with an `$` ;)

Comment: @MightyBadaboom - no :) Just a typo but thanks for pointing it out haha

Comment: This is good but First i want List of placeholders and accordingly i want to change the value.

Comment: Okay liked your recommendation. Just one more question how to apply $ on a string variable? Query i get is in string variable.

Comment: @Milanchavda - Not sure because I need to see the relevant code first. But this this a followup question and should be part of a separate SO question. Please try googling it to see if there are previously asked questions about the matter

Answer (score 2):

One solution could be doing like this :
You replace the {Id}, {Number}, {Address} by {0}, {1}, {2}, like this.

```
Insert into Emp(Id,Name,Number,Address) values({0},"Abc",{1},{2});
```

Then you do this :

```
myString = string.Format(myString, "123", "55668878", "test address");
```

With this solution you don't have to work with regex of complex things.